# Viewpager setCurrentItem() doesn't update onPageSelected()

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

When I swipe between questions, it loads current page number correctly

BUT when I use next button,  first click doesnt loads pagenumber ( I mean `onPageSelected()` doesnt work.)  second and other clicks loads content but it loads 1 page previous.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    QuestionPagerAdapter mAdapter = new QuestionPagerAdapter();

    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            tv.setText( mPager.getCurrentItem()+"");
        }

    };

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

    Question.next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        mPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1));
        }
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        int a = mPager.getCurrentItem();
        i += a;
        return i;
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you post more code than this, can't really do much with this. Can you show where you set the page listener etc. Just more code can't solve it with this.

Comment: Thanks, added more code.

Comment: What is 'Question'? Is fragment or activity? And 'Next' is button?

Comment: Check next onCliklitsener is executing?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just doing this in your listener:

mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);